# Proof utilizing Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, probability-inequalities

I'm being asked to show that $P(|X-\mu|\geq t) \leq \beta_4/t^4,$ where $\beta_4=E((X-\mu)^4)$.

I'm familiar with Chebyshev's Inequality, which similarly states that $P(|X-\mu|\geq t) \leq \sigma^2/t^2,$ and I know that $\sigma^2 = E((X-\mu)^2), $ but the furthest I get with this knowledge is that $P(|X-\mu|\geq t) \leq E((X-\mu)^2)/t^2.$

Apparently I somehow need to turn $E((X-\mu)^2)/t^2$ into $E((X-\mu)^4)/t^4.$ It doesn't seem like squaring this would help since $E((X-\mu)^2)^2 \neq E((X-\mu)^4),$ and I'd also have to square the $P(|X-\mu|\geq t)$ term also, which was not done in the final answer I'm asked to show. How can I prove this inequality?

Comment: Look at any proof of Chebyshev's Inequality.  Change the power "2" to "4."  Everything goes through the same and results in what you want to show.

Comment: @Dan W I added a self study tag to your question.

Answer (score 5):

In statistics, it's important to remember what a theorem *says,* so you can apply it.  But in mathematics it's usually more important to remember *why a theorem is true,* so that you really understand it and can generalize it.  This is that kind of situation.

---

Observe that when the power $p \ge 1,$ the gray area, weighted by the probability of $X,$ cannot exceed the area under the curve $y = |(x-\mu)/t|^p$ (yellow plus gray), weighted by the same probability distribution.

[image: Figure]

**Write this inequality in terms of expectations.**  The case $p=2$ proves Chebyshev's Inequality.  Pick a suitable value of $p$ to finish your proof.

Comment: I love the diagram, it says everything.